# Breaking out of nested for loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

How can I use break and/or continue statements to return to the first line of the while loop  at points 1, 2 and 3, for example, as indicated in the pseudocode?

Suppose I have a scenario reminiscent of the following:

```
while(condition) {
    // want to return to this point
    for (Integer x : xs) {
        // point 1
        for (Integer y : ys) {
            // point 2
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    for (Integer a : as) {
        for (Integer b : bs) {
            // point 3
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there some kind of break statement" i believe, there is only one kind of break exist

Comment: @coders: thanks - have edited for clarity.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I very much disagree that this post is a duplicate. The fact that two different types of loops are involved and that there are multiple sequential inner loops makes this question *very* different from the others on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a label such as :

```
outer:
while(condition) {
// want to return to this point
for (Integer x : xs) {
    // point 1
    for (Integer y : ys) {
        // point 2
        ...
    }
    ...
}
for (Integer a : as) {
    for (Integer b : bs) {
        // point 3
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

}

and you can then use `break outer;` to escape the while loop. This works with nested for loops as well, but I try not to overuse labels

As pointed out by @Peter, use `continue outer;` if you wish to finish the current outer iteration early and continue on to the next, as opposed to escaping the while loop.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware you could use labels with different types of loops. That's really helpful.

Comment: +1 labels are usually in UPPER_CASE. I assume you want `continue outer;` Break will exit that loop as well.

Comment: @Froskoy You can break out of any block of code, it doesn't have to be a loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey makes a good point, follow the kind of naming convention used for CONSTANTS

Answer (score 2):

You can do that :

```
here:
while(condition) {
   for (Integer x : xs) {
        // point 1
        for (Integer y : ys) {
            break here;
        }
    }
```

The break statement, with or without label, [is described in the Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) :

> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the
>   innermost enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the
>   immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is
>   called the break target, then immediately completes normally.
>
> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; this statement, which is called the break
>   target, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the break
>   target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.

Answer (score 2):

[**label**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) your Loops with syntax

`LABEL: LoopType` and later you can use **Break Statement** to get out of a certain loop with `break LABEL;`.

```
OUT: while(somecond){
IN:for(...) {
   INNER: for(...){
break IN;// will get you outta IN and INNER for loop
}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
loop:
while(condition) {
// want to return to this point
for (Integer x : xs) {
    continue loop:
    for (Integer y : ys) {
        continue loop:
        ...
    }
    ...
}
for (Integer a : as) {
    for (Integer b : bs) {
        continue loop:
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: What's the difference between using break and continue in this situation?

Comment: Continue returns to beginig of loop, break exits loop

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use the `break` statement with a label:

```
SOME_LABEL:
   // ... some code here
   break SOME_LABEL;
```

used sparingly, this is a clean way to break out of multiple nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this posted here stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java handles the same question.

Comment: That actually doesn't answer my question, or at least I thought it didn't when I first viewed it before reading the other answers here, because of the mixed for and while loops, and breaking out at the subtly different points.