# Creating a random output from an user input array

Tags: java, arrays, random, count

```
public class decisionMaker {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String option[] = new String[10];
        // Output

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the next option:");
            option[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            System.out.println("option:   ");
            System.out.println("option[i]+"             ");
        }
    // Output
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add a count to the options, exit and end the program after entering a certain letter or number, and how to create a random output from the user input. I want it to give me one option that I had input at random. Can anyone help me with one or a few of these things. I'm trying to learn to code on my own, and I'm stuck on these.

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question and have a look here: [mcve], btw javascript !== java

Comment: it would be good if you post code instead of an image?

Comment: Please note that *javascript* has absolutely nothing to do with *java*.

Comment: Let start at the begining here,  Welcome on SO ! Could you try to explain a bit more your problem. You have asked two questions here I believe. **1.** How to generate a Random number _based on user input_ **2.** How to exit a loop. Could you confirm this ? Both already have answers on SO. **1.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range **2.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275195/breaking-out-of-a-for-loop-in-java

Answer (score 1):

### Randomness

You can generate random numbers using `java.util.Random;`:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SomeClass{
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt());
    }
}
```

### About some broken code:

If you want to print out the *value* of a variable with `System.out.println()` then you need only type the variable *without any quotation marks*. The code you've written below will not compile:

```
System.out.println("option:   ");
System.out.println("option[i]+"             ");
```

Assuming that's what you want to do, it should instead be written as:

```
System.out.println("option: ");
System.out.println(option[i]);
```

Or even `System.out.println("option: \n"+option[i]);`

(The escape sequence `\n` when placed inside of quotation marks just indicates to the console to add a new line.)

### Scanner:

Additionally, as nick zoum pointed out, your `Scanner` object should be initialized *outside* of the `for` loop, such as right underneath of the `main()` method.

Please comment below if you need clarification or if I misunderstood what you were looking for. It was very hard to understand your question.

Comment: Can you add to your answer that OP should move the `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` outside of the loop.

Comment: Good eye @nickzoum. I've edited it to include your help

Comment: The first part is probably a typo from OP since `"option[i]+"             "` i not a a String, this can't compile. And this could also be writen like `System.out.println("option: \n%s", option[i]);` ;)

Comment: Correct @AxelH, that's what I'm pointing out in my answer.

Comment: The typo is probably not part of the question, this could probably be confirm by the OP.

Comment: Good point @AlexH. It may be slightly off-topic for me to have included that in my answer. Since the OP said "*I'm trying to learn to code on my own, and I'm stuck on these*" though, I figured I would try to be as helpful as possible. I've creeped SO for a long time but only recently started getting involved so your judgement is probably better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public class DecisionMaker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // output
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = getInt(scanner);
        String option[] = new String[size];
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the next option:");
            option[index] = scanner.next();
        }
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * size);
        System.out.println(option[index]);
        scanner.close();
        // output
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner scanner) {
        int size = 0;
        while (size <= 0) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    size = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
            if (size <= 0) {
                System.out.println("The input: " + scanner.next() + " is not a valid value.");
            }
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

### How the program works:

- The `Scanner` is initialized in the beginning and there is only
  one instance of it.
- Then the program will wait until the user inserts a valid number for
  the size of options.
- The next 5 lines were essentially copied from your code.
- Finally we get a random `Integer` in the range of `0 - (size - 1)` and print
  the String of the array with that index.