# Break a while loop, where there's a try-catch block

Tags: java

I have a While loop, and a try catch block within it. How can i add a break statement in the catch statement to break the while loop. I don't want to use a DO-WHILE loop because i just have a few minutes to submit my code, and i don't want to break the program by making the change. But, later on i will consider changing the code using a DO-WHILE statement.

```
while (true) {
try {
// something here
} catch (Exception e) {

// I need to break the forever while loop here
}
}
```

Comment: break; ??? does this work

Answer (score 8):

```
try {
// something here
    while (true) {
    // While body here.
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

// I need to break the forever while loop here
}
}
```

You can move the while loop inside the try catch body. This will act EXACTLY the same programmatically, but all errors will be caught and there's no need for a do-while. This looks a lot nicer, and makes more semantic sense.

Moreover, just add the word `break;` in the catch block, and it will stop the running of your loop.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want the while loop in the try-catch block. For example, if he only needs try/catch for some kind of read/write/database access. In that case, adding break in the catch block sounds like the best solution.

Comment: Furthermore, a while(true) loop within a try-catch block does not look nice to me whichever way you spin it :-)

Comment: It won't 'act exactly the same programmatically'. It depends entirely on what's inside the `catch` block. And no code motion is required to solve this non-problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a break statement in the catch block

Answer (score 1):

Well there are multiple approaches

**Approach1 - by reversing the While Condition variable**

```
boolean notDone = true;
while(notDone) {
    try {
    // something here
    } catch (Exception e) {             
        notDone = false;
    }
}
```

**Approach2 - Using break statement**

```
while(notDone) {
    try {
    // something here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Approach 3 - moving the catch block outside of while**

```
try {
        while(notDone) {

        }       
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another loop in the catch clause (which would be weird), just use `break;`.

try-catch is not a loop, so the break affects the first containing loop, which seems to be the while.

Answer (score 0):

It would work.

But what you should do is leaving the loop **because** you had an exception like:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        // something here
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do whatever in the catch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a boolean variable that is initially true in your while loop, and that you set to false anywhere in either your try or catch statement. This way, you can break the loop you have given even if there are nested loops inside it.

```
boolean notDone = true;
while(notDone) {
try {
// something here
} catch (Exception e) {
// I need to break the forever while loop here
notDone = false;
}
```

You can use off course use the inverted version, using a "done" boolean instead. This causes you to need to call an invert inside the while-loop for each iteration. It's a trade-off between minor-performance and increased code-readability.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i add a break statement in the catch statement to break the while loop

Just do exactly that. Add a `break` statement in the `catch` statement. It will break out of the `while` loop.

Not a real question.

Answer (score -1):

Just name your loop and break it
For example

```
Lable:
while (true) {
    try {
        // something here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //  I need to break the forever while loop here
        break Lable;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Label`. loops like the `goto` statement in C++

Comment: @Illep check that http://stackoverflow.com/q/886955/1824361

Comment: It's not even a good practice even if it existed in Java. Using Goto statement means something is not right in your logic.