# Returning value (or nothing) for outer function from inner function of nested functions in Java

Tags: java, android, function, methods, nested

Is there any way to return value (or just `return;`) for the outer function from the inner function?

My question is similar to this question:
[Breaking out of nested loops in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java), but the difference is that in this question the asker asked about breaking the outer loop in nested loops, and I ask about returning for the outer function in nested functions.

```java
public void outerFunction ()
{
    runOnUiThread (new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            // Here i want to return;, so the function will not continue after runOnUiThread
        }
    });

    // Code here should not run.

}
```

Comment: What you are looking at is, annoymous thread instance as part of method invocation, not function/method inside function/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `runOnUiThread` accepts a `Runnable` argument. We can assume it uses its `run()` method somewhere. For example, if the method was

```
public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    // do a bunch of stuff
    // some more logic
    runnable.run();
    // more logic
    return;
}
```

You can't force a `return` of the calling method (`runOnUiThread()`) from the called method (`run()`). You can however throw an `Exception` within the called method that will stop all execution, but you won't necessarily know where that gets caught.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  But I assume you are not very familiar with multi-threading.

The code within `Runnable` and the code after the call to `runOnUiThread` actually run at the same time, but on different threads.  So it is light-years away from nested loops, or from single-threaded nested methods calls.

You can actually make a "blocking" call to another thread to wait for a value, but I don't think it's appropriate to write all of this out in a stackoverflow answer.  You should read up on multi-threading and I strongly recommend [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).  But you should be warned that it is not a trivial topic that you can pick up in a few days.  You can also look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures); the interface `Future` implements the "blocking" call I was referring to.

**EDIT**
I wrote the above thinking in Java.  Things are more complicated with Android since in order to use a `Future`, you would need to get an `ExecutorService` for the UI thread, and I'm not sure that is possible.

There are many Android specific multi-threading constructs (see for example [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_handler2), or the official doc).  It is certainly possible to solve your problem, but we don't have enough details.  Also, you should probably not try to find a quick fix for your problem, but rethink your whole design so that fits naturally within the Android multi-threading paradigm.