# VBA: Break Out of Deeply Nested If Statements

Tags: vba, if-statement, break, control-flow, nested-if

Typically when I want to break out of a statement I just set a `boolean` flag for control flow, but I have a special case with many nested `If` statements and I'd really like to have a way to break out of several with one simple statement.

In Java you can [name a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java) and then break to that location; is there anything like that for VBA that can be used from a deeply nested location in `If` statements? I know VBA has the [Exit statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx) for loops (`while`, `for`, etc), so I'm wondering if there is something similar for `If`s.

Ideally I'd like to do something this:

```
If ...
    *NAMED_IF*
    If ...
         If ...
          :
            *break out of NAMED_IF*
          :
        End If
    End If
    *Now We end up at this control position*
End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an if-statement specific method to break out of nested if-statements, but you could use the `GoTo`-statement instead:

```
If ...
    '*NAMED_IF*
    If ...
         If ...

            '*break out of NAMED_IF*'
            GoTo GoToHere

        End If
    End If
End If

'*Now We end up at this control position*
GoToHere:
```

Comment: This is great - according to the spec, you can even go to a line number: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/69whc95c.aspx

Comment: @user1205577 - I cannot tell if you are being facetious :-)

Comment: A Word of warning... overused goto statements make your code incredibly difficult to change at a later date by a different developer.  If you need to break out of a large block of code, then that block of code should be a function.