# Java - Breaking out of a loop under certain conditions while parsing through text file

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader

I'm currently reading through a text file that looks something like this:

```
123 (1.0,4.4) (4,5)
4 (2,1) (6.1,7) (1,3) (1,2)
...
89122 (3,1) (56.1,1) (1.7,2)
```

It begins with a number followed by at least one pair of coordinates in the form (x,y). My goal: If one of the coordinates on the line matches what I'm looking for, I want to add the tag (the first number) to an arraylist and then break out of the loop right away. This is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));

String pattern =  "([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = null;
String line;
double x,y;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] temp = line.split(" ", 2);  //this splits the tag from the rest of the line, which are pairs of (x,y)
    m = p.matcher(temp[1]);
    while(m.find()) {
        x = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        y = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));

        if(x > 100 || y > 100) {
            matches.add(temp[0]);
            break; // ***this only breaks out of this single if, but what I really want is to break out of the m.find() while loop and get reader to read in the next line.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is (* * *), commented out in the code above. How do I break out of the loop properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: Consider switching to a language whose regex implementation supports multiple matches from the same group, such as C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label your loop

```
OUTER:while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
String[] temp = line.split(" ", 2);  //this splits the tag from the rest of the line, which are pairs of (x,y)
m = p.matcher(temp[1]);
INNER:while(m.find()) {
    x = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    y = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));

    if(x > 100 || y > 100) {
        matches.add(temp[0]);
        break INNER; // ***this breaks the loop named INNER
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Use [branching labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) to direct the break statement to a specific loop

```
outer:
    while(....) {
        while(....) {
            if(....)
                break outer;
        }
    }
```

See also: [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can break the outer loop by using labels, but it's a bad practice. You have two options here:

- Isolate the find functionality in a separate method and do `return` instead of `break` (best approach since you'll be able to reuse the method later)
- Declare a `boolean found = false;` variable, set it to true when you found the stuff you were looking for and then check it in the outer loop

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. However, I've never heard of labeling loops before, so I'm going to try it even if it's bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean flag:

```
boolean endLoop = false;
while(!endLoop && (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] temp = line.split(" ", 2);  //this splits the tag from the rest of the line, which are pairs of (x,y)
    m = p.matcher(temp[1]);
    while(m.find()) {
        x = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        y = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));

        if(x > 100 || y > 100) {
            matches.add(temp[0]);
            endLoop = true; 
        }
    }
}
```