# Break while loop inside for loop Java

Tags: java, loops

Loop is work fine.

```
  while (!(list.contains("NORTH SOUTH") || list.contains("SOUTH NORTH") || list.contains("WEST EAST") || list.contains("EAST WEST"))) {


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); k++) {
                if (list.get(i).contains("NORTH") && list.get(k).contains("SOUTH") ||
                    list.get(i).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(k).contains("NORTH") ||
                    list.get(i).contains("WEST") && list.get(k).contains("EAST") ||
                    list.get(i).contains("EAST") && list.get(k).contains("WEST")) {
                    list.remove(i);
                    list.remove(k - 1);


                  }
            }
        }
```

My question is:

How to exit while loop with saving list with results?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java) helps?

Comment: As an aside `list.remove(k);` before `list.remove(i);` so you don’t need to subtract 1. It will be clearer to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the break statement inside the if condition and set a boolean value to a variable.check for the status of that boolean variable just after the for loop ends.if its true then use a break statement to break out of the while loop.

```
while (!(list.contains("NORTH SOUTH") || list.contains("SOUTH NORTH") || list.contains("WEST EAST") || list.contains("EAST WEST"))) {

    boolean conditionChecker=false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); k++) {
            if (list.get(i).contains("NORTH") && list.get(k).contains("SOUTH") ||
                list.get(i).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(k).contains("NORTH") ||
                list.get(i).contains("WEST") && list.get(k).contains("EAST") ||
                list.get(i).contains("EAST") && list.get(k).contains("WEST")) {
                list.remove(i);
                list.remove(k - 1);
                conditionChecker=true;
                break;

              }
        }
        if(conditionChecker==true){
          break;      
           }
    }
```

Comment: conditionChecker shoud set true if condition is observed. In this code code conditionChecker set true after first check, It may have several checks. So I need to break when condition in while loop is observed.

Comment: the code i have provided will do those.

Answer (score -2):

Possible duplicate of:
[Break while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550985/how-to-break-a-while-loop-from-an-if-condition-inside-the-while-loop/23551051)

Comment: If you want to suggest a duplicate use the `flag` button under the question, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry but there is no duplicate flag

Comment: Because the question was already closed. This isn't an answer nonetheless.