# Continue at first loop , inside the second loop

Tags: java, loops, keyword

This will help you understand it better:

```
for(Object o : objects){//first loop
    for(int j = 0; i < y; j++){//second loop

        if(something_is_true)
            stop second loop , continue first loop 

    }
}
```

Am i supposed to use the continue keyword for that"?

Comment: You could use "while" instead of for, for the second loop

Comment: add break; statement in your if condition. break always transfer control out to the current loop only. In your case if you put break statement in if block then it will always take you out to first loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, use 'break'.

```
for(Object o : objects){//first loop
  for(int j = 0; i < y; j++){//second loop

    if(something_is_true)
       break;

  }
}
```

Comment: The question asked for continuing the first loop from the second loop, not breaking the second loop. This should not be the accepted answer or the question should be reformulated. (That matters in the case the first loop has some instructions after the second loop).

Comment: I agree with @AW5 this is failing to meet the logical requirements wand will be misleading researchers.  I am looking for the equivalent of `continue 2`, but it seems (after researching for a while) that javascript doesn't offer this kind of control.  For anyone who does [tag:javascript] page curation on SO, this question has some duplicate page consolidation to do.

Comment: Downvoted because this approach will still run code after the inner loop.  The answer with the most votes makes this clear and should be accepted instead.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use a `label`:

```
myLabel: for(Object o : objects){//first loop
    for(int j = 0; i < y; j++){//second loop

        if(something_is_true) {
            continue myLabel;
        }
    }
    //code that will be skipped if you continue to myLabel
    //but will not be skipped if you 'break' inside inner loop.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You couuld use "while" instead of "for", for the second loop:

```
for(Object o : objects){//first loop
  int counter=0;
  while(!something_is_true && counter<y){//second loop
    counter++
    if(something happens)
      something_is_true=true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Adding the flag doesn't require using `while`; if you have an initialization, test, and increment, `for` is the correct choice.

Comment: It is another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better approach:

```
for(Object o : objects)
{
     int j = 0
     while(j < y && something_is_true)
     {
       do_whatever;
       j++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

You can use `break` with a label for the outer loop. For example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    outerloop:
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (i * j > 6) {
          System.out.println("Breaking");
          break outerloop;
        }
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
Breaking
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use [javascript labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

its better choice if you do something after the inner loop inside each iteration of the outer loop, and you want to skip it and go to next outer loop iteration:

```
loop1: // an identifier to the first loop statement
for (...) {
   for (...) {
      if (...) continue loop1;
   }
   doSomething() // this also skips as well
}
```

but if you use `break;` to terminate the execution of inner loop, the part after the inner loop (`doSomething()` in the example above) still executes before the next iteration of outer loop start.

Answer (score -1):

No. Use `break` . That will break you out of the inner loop and you'll continue with the outer loop.

```
for(Object o : objects){//first loop
  for(int j = 0; i < y; j++){//second loop
    if(something_is_true) break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ Spundun: Get used to it. :-) People downvote, and people comment, and they're not usually the same people. (In fact, the closest thing to guidance you'll see from SO management and moderators is that saying why you downvoted is usually counter-productive for the site.) If you get an answer downvoted, look at it and ask why someone would, and if you don't figure it out don't worry about it. (I'm not seeing an issue with your answer, FWIW.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the support and taking the time to respond :)

Comment: Downvoted because this approach will still run code after the inner loop.  The answer with the most votes makes this clear and should be accepted instead.

Answer (score -1):

If your objective is to get out of the second loop and continue the first you just need to call break. No need for continue (it's not even called).