# how to stop While-Do Loop?

Tags: java

the `System.out.print("\n\n\t\t Do you want to see the next record ? [y/n]");` keeps repeating and repeating how can i stop it when the Records becomes 0.

```
case 3: //Previous
    if (recno!=0) {
        String pre;

        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t   Previous Record");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t    Employee Number: EMP-"+EmpNo[recno]);
        System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Employee Name: "+EmpName[recno]);
        System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Salary: "+Salary[recno]);
        System.out.print("\n\t_________________________________________________________________");

        do {
            System.out.print("\n\n\t\t  Do you want to see the next record ? [y/n]");
            pre = reader.readLine();

            if(pre.equals("y")) {
                recno--;
                System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t    Employee Number: EMP-"+EmpNo[recno]);
                System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Employee Name: "+EmpName[recno]);
                System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Salary: "+Salary[recno]);
            }

            menu = display.charAt(0);
            System.out.print("\n\t_________________________________________________________________");
        } while(menu=='n');

        System.out.println("Thank You for Using this Program!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\tRecord Not Found!");
    }

break;
```

Comment: please prettify your code. it's indented too much to the right. thnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: You probably should use a `while` in a do-while loop

Comment: @jhobbie There's a `while` there, it's just way over to the right where it's hard to find.  It took me a ... ummm, *while* to find it too.

Comment: You need to show more code snippet like What is `menu` declared as variable? and what is `display`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the loop use `if (condition) break;` with the proper condition; put this code in the proper place inside the loop.

Comment: The OP's code is inside a `switch`. So you'd need to make a labelled thingy to break out into.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young No, OP has a do-while inside the switch, this is how I understood it at least.

Comment: Ah, I thought they wanted to break out of the switch itself; perhaps I misread the code. Okay, have an upvote.

Comment: i put the break; in the If(condition) it only let me loop once, It need to stop when the record is 0

Comment: This means you didn't use the proper logical condition.

Answer (score 1):

You use the key-word "break".

In any loop, whether it is a while, do-while, or for-loop, you can always break the loop with the keyword as a statement "break".

So like this:

```
do {
     if(condition) {
          break;
     }
while(condition);
```

Comment: i put the break; in the If(condition) it only let me loop once, It need to stop when the record is 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for a [break](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java) shows the break in action. The accepted answer shows how to break out of two loops.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the do-while loop condition is determined by the first character of `display` being "n".  In your loop, `display` is never updated, so the condition that "n" is the first letter of `display` is never met.  You can also choose to change your logic as the other answers have suggested by using the `break` statement.