# How to use label in java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I need to help.
I want to use label in java. Like label in c, but goto can't use in java. How move to label in java?
 Program :

```
ulang:
switch (menu){
case 1 : input(); goto ulang;
break;
}
```

How to change code to java code ?

Comment: You better use a loop.
Seems you can use labels in a loop, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430630/how-to-use-goto-statement-correctly

Comment: Even in C, `goto` should be used rarely and only to go down, never up (like in your example).

Comment: Don't use `goto`. There are other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use looping if you want to make a repetition

```
do{
   /* code to display your menu here */
   switch(pilih){
      case 1 : input();break;
      case 2 : ..../*continue with your other selection*/
   }

}while(pilih!=5) // assume 5 is the exit choice
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `goto` in Java. I suggest to use loops.

```
while (true) {
  switch (menu){
    case 1 : input(); continue;
    break;
  }
  break;
}
```

---

Bellow does not work in Java as I expected, it makes a labeled *switch* statement and *break + label* breaks a *switch*, does not go to a label (thanks @xiaofeng.li and @YatiSawhney):

```
ulang:
switch (menu) {
  case 1 : input(); break ulang;
}
```

Read the SO article [Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support `goto`. Although you can use the labelled `break` and `continue` in nested loops and switch statements, they are just there to tell the compiler which block of code you are referring to, not actually jumping to that location. For example, you can write:

```
ulang:
switch(menu) {
case 1: input(); break ulang; // break the switch labelled by 'ulang'
}
```

But it's just the same as

```
switch(menu) {
case 1: input(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend using labels(goto). (Just for the sake of knowledge)The following is the snippet that will let you understand the same. `Break` with a `label` will get you out of the outer loop which has got the label.

```
label: for( initialization ; condition ; modification ){

    for( initialization ; condition ; modification ){
        if(condition){
            break label;
        }
    }

}
```