# switching to first line of while loop in java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Sorry, I am new to Java!
I have a question regarding using multiple if statements in a loop like a while.
I will make clear my question through an example.
if condition 1 is wrong, how can we switch to the while again( without processing other conditions)?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while(){
            if(condition1){

            if(condition2){

            if(condition3){

                   }    

            }
```

Comment: Have a look at things like continue, or break. First goes back to top of loop. Last exits  look. You can also nest loops and append a tag to continue or break. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431031/495157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keyword

```
continue;
```

to skip processing and proceed with next loop iteration.

The Keyword

```
break;
```

would completely jump out of the loop.

Better design in your case would be nesting the if statements:

```
if (condition1) {
    if (condition2) {
    ...
    }
}
```

So the next condition is only checked when the further one is true.

If you do so, you don't have to struggle with `continue;` statements.

You are also able to combine multiple conditions in one `if` statement:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    // do something
}
```

In this case code is only executed when all conditions are true. If the first condition is false, the second condition will not even be checked because `false && true` would be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(){
  if(condition1) {
      if(condition2) {
          if(condition3) {
          }
      }
  }
}
```