# What does this syntax "search: " mean in java

Tags: java

So I was grinding leetcode and came across a solution that looked like this. What does the syntax "search:" and "continue search;" do? I have never seen this syntax before when I write for-loop. Thanks in advance!

```
public boolean isAlienSorted(String[] words, String order) {
    int[] index = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); ++i)
        index[order.charAt(i) - 'a'] = i;

    search: for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; ++i) {
        String word1 = words[i];
        String word2 = words[i+1];

        // Find the first difference word1[k] != word2[k].
        for (int k = 0; k < Math.min(word1.length(), word2.length()); ++k) {
            if (word1.charAt(k) != word2.charAt(k)) {
                // If they compare badly, it's not sorted.
                if (index[word1.charAt(k) - 'a'] > index[word2.charAt(k) - 'a'])
                    return false;
                continue search;
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find a first difference, the
        // words are like ("app", "apple").
        if (word1.length() > word2.length())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That's a label (see [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430630/how-to-use-goto-statement-correctly) – [similar to C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm)), it's rather unnecessary here for solving the problem.
- The following solution would simply get through:

```
class Solution {

    int[] letterMap = new int[26];

    public final boolean isAlienSorted(
        final String[] words,
        final String order
    ) {
        for (int index = 0; index < order.length(); index++) {
            letterMap[order.charAt(index) - 'a'] = index;
        }

        for (int index = 1; index < words.length; index++)
            if (wordIsLarger(words[index - 1], words[index])) {
                return false;
            }

        return true;
    }

    private final boolean wordIsLarger(
        final String a,
        final String b
    ) {
        final int lengthA = a.length();
        final int lengthB = b.length();

        for (int index = 0; index < lengthA && index < lengthB; index++)
            if (a.charAt(index) != b.charAt(index)) {
                return letterMap[a.charAt(index) - 'a'] > letterMap[b.charAt(index) - 'a'];
            }

        return lengthA > lengthB;
    }
}
```

---

If we would format it, we can see much easier:

```
public boolean isAlienSorted(String[] words, String order) {
    int[] index = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); ++i) {
        index[order.charAt(i) - 'a'] = i;
    }

    search:

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; ++i) {
        String word1 = words[i];
        String word2 = words[i + 1];

        // Find the first difference word1[k] != word2[k].
        for (int k = 0; k < Math.min(word1.length(), word2.length()); ++k) {
            if (word1.charAt(k) != word2.charAt(k)) {
                // If they compare badly, it's not sorted.
                if (index[word1.charAt(k) - 'a'] > index[word2.charAt(k) - 'a'])
                { return false; }

                continue search;
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find a first difference, the
        // words are like ("app", "apple").
        if (word1.length() > word2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [labeled continue](https://www.codespeedy.com/labelled-continue-statement-in-java/#:%7E:text=This%20tutorial%20is%20about%20labelled%20continue%20statement%20in,the%20control%20of%20execution%20is%20to%20be%20transferred.). This is mostly used when there are multilevel loops. And we want to [continue to outer loop directly from inner loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/break-continue-and-label-in-Java-loop).

Although it is highly recommended to avoid it.