# How to break continue a nested for-loop inside a while-loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, break

Can I use break on a nested for-loop to get back to outer while-loop and use `continue` from inside the for-loop to force the while-loop to keep going? I can not get the for-loop conditions into my while-loop conditions so the while-loop might stop if I cannot continue on a specifically meet situation.

```
while(...some conditions...){
    ...print stuff
    for(...some instances are arrays, condition loop array...){
        if(...index meets conditions...){
            ...print once, some arrays might meet condition on multiple index
            break; //to prevent multiple printings
        }
    continue; //i don't want to force another while iteration if(false)
    //or is this continue for(loop) anyway?
    }
continue; //is this not essentially a while(true) loop with no return?
}
```

The reason I can not get the for-loop conditions into the while conditions is because there are more if conditions between the two loops like `if(array == null)` and if-condition `x == true` `getArray()` needs to be called if array is not passed in. Most of the time condition `y` and `z` print from while-loop but sometimes condition `x` is met so I need the for-loop. It's after the printing of the for-loop `if(index true))` I need the while-loop to go again that I'm stuck with? Sometime this might happen from while-loop conditions anyway but I can see that it wont always, further more if for-loop `if(index false))` is meet I don't want to force the while loop as this could get costly in run time processing and could possibly result in an endless loop.

PS I am a junior programer, I'm not even sure it this is possible? 
or makes sense, sorry if its a stupid question

Comment: You can use labels to break or continue loops http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java

Comment: I am an experienced programmer, use break and continue, but would keep it simple. Having `boolean active = ...; while (active) {` offers a bit more control.

Comment: @usb I agree but without any other information it's one of the cleanest way to jump out of a loop if a certain condition is true.

Answer (score 9):

you can name your loops like this:

```
namedLoop: for(...) {
    // access your namedloop
    break namedLoop;
}
```

Comment: Functions should replace all label-goto cases. Spaghetti code is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I am not saying that this is the best way to go and it surely hurts the readability and maintenance, but depending on the complexity of the designed code it is just a bit more simple (breaking a finished sorted array in a sorting routine for example)

Comment: @ Kevin can i do this as `continue namedLoop;` from inside the nested for(loop)?

Answer (score 2):

You can `break` with label.

Here is a complete example showing it:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BreakWithLabelDemo.java

Basically the code is similar to this:

```
:myLabel


for (...) {
    for(...) {
        ...
        break myLabel; // Exit from both for loops
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`continue` and `break` apply to the immediate current scope, so if you're inside the `for`, it will apply to the `for`.

You can store the comparison result on a boolean variable to check if you want to `continue`.

I'm not a big fan of `break` and `continue`, it hinders readability in my opinion. You can acheive the same behavior using a different code structuring.