# Numbers from 1 to 30 indivisible by 3

Tags: java, math

So I started learning Java only a few days ago and I'm doing really well except for this one exercise that boggles my mind. So the exercise is to "Write a program which displays all numbers from 1 to 30 indivisible by 3". So this is easy:

```
class numbers {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i <=30; i++){
            switch(i % 3){
                case 0 :
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Except one of the variants says "use `break` after divisibility by 3 is detected. Now I'm not sure if hte `break` used in the code above is correct, as it is a part of `switch`. I was wondering if there was an other way to do it.

Comment: This seems to give the desired output. What's your concern about the code?

Comment: Do you mean you want a statement inside the `switch` that breaks out of the `for` loop?  Try named loops.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java, which should apply even though you don't have a nested loop.

Comment: It IS the desired output. There a few variants to it, though - like "use `continue`", "don't use `continue`" etc. One of them says "use `break` when divisibility by 3 is detected" and and I'd like to know if there is an other way to do so - i.e. with `break` but without `switch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some fixes:

1. class names should start with Upper letter, name class `Numbers`, not `numbers`
2. start iterating from 1, not from 0, because you are displaying numbers in range  [1..30].
3. Because here you have only 2 possibilities (is or is not indivisible), replace switch with if statement. Switch is more suited for a large range of conditions.
4. Most important. Using break will make you get out of the loop. Using continue will skip this loop and go to next iteration.

So now your code should look shorted and cleaner:)

```
class Numbers {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i <=30; i++){
            if(i % 3 == 0){
             continue;
            }
             System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could go with shorter version:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=30; i++){
    if(i % 3 != 0){
       System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This snipplet will display: 1,2,4,5,7,8,10...29. So all numbers in given range that are n%3!=0

Answer (score 1):

Another short solution.

As we know that from 1 to 30 there are only 10 numbers divisible by 3, we make ten loops to print them all.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; ++i) {
    System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n", i++, i++);
}
```

The idea is to print the two numbers before the one which is divisible by 3 and skip the one which is divisible.

- the counter `i` starts at 1
- the first `%d`in `System.out.printf` prints current `i` (i=1) and increase it by 1 (i=2)
- the second `%d`in `System.out.printf` prints current `i` (i=2) and increase it by 1 (i=3)
- the end condition of the `for-loop` increase `i` by 1 (i=4)
- repeat till the end condition `i <= 30` is false

**edit** A more readable version (as proposed by ajb)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i += 3) {
    System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n", i, i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Aack.  This kind of mucking with the loop index leads to unreadable code.  A better way to express the same idea: `for (int i=1; i<=30; i+=3) { System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n", i, i+1); }`

Comment: @ajb Agree. I amend my answer and added your version.

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK - if `i % 3` results in 0, nothing is printed. Since there are only two possiblities I would rewrite as if-statement:

```
if( ( i % 3 ) != 0 )
{
   System.out.println( i );
}
```

Is in my opinion better readable and conveys the intent more clearly.

More on the actual statement:

```
switch( i % 3 )
{
      case 0:
         //do nothing
       break; // leave switch - statement
      ...
}
```

The break is needed to leave the switch statement. So yes, it is necessary.