# Java program exit function not working

Tags: java, testing

i'm a newbie to java so i decided to create a simple program that prints out even numbers. I tried to make it exit a while loop if you answered no to the question but it just keeps on going.

Here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String continueYorN = "Y";
    int i = 0;
    while (continueYorN.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){

        while(i >= 0){
            i++;
            if((i%2) == 0){
                System.out.println(i);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to generate another even number?");
            continueYorN = userInput.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You program gets stuck in the inner loop and never gets a chance to read user input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop has no `break condition` (i.e, something that stop the loop in some condition), so it will continue forever.

You should replace the inner `while` with something like that:

```
while(i >= 0){
        i++;
        if((i%2) == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
    }
```