# Return to the first loop in a nested loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm making an ATM machine program for my case study. How can I return to the first output which is the main menu (the one with balance inquiry etc.) after the user pressed cancel for example (I didn't code it yet).

From comment: "how can i display the same window (which is the main menu) if for example the user finished withdrawing."

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class casestudy
    {
         public static void main (String Args [])
         {
          Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
          String acct[]={"0123-4567-8901", "2345-6789-0123", "3456-7890-1234","4567-8901-2345", "5678-9012-3456"};
          String name[]={"Dina Balle", "Mally Gaya", "Toto Lee", "Mina Mahal", "Cory Pot"};
          int bal[]={5000, 0, 10000, 2500, 10000};
          int pinarr []={0000, 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555};
          int wdamount=0;
          int depamount =0;
          int pinattempt=0;
          int wrongall=0;
          boolean correct = false;
          boolean wrong = false;

          String g=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("WELCOME TO FILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION!\n\nPress [C] if you are a CUSTOMER, [A] if you are an ADMINISTRATOR: ");
      char level = g.charAt(0);
      switch (level)
      {

        case 'A':
        case 'a': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HEHE");break;
        default : JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID CODE!"); System.exit(0); break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
        {   
         String a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("FILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n===========================================\nPress [S] to START TRANSACTION and [Q] to QUIT: ");
         char choice = a.charAt(0);
         switch (choice)
         {

           case 'Q': 
           case 'q': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The program will now exit"); System.exit(0); break; 
           default : JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INVALID SELECTION!");  System.exit(0); break;

          case 'S':
          case 's':
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\n\n\t\t\tSTART TRANSACTION!");
          while ((pinattempt!=3)&&(correct=true))
          {
           int pin=Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your PIN: "));
           switch (pin)
           {
             case 1111:
             {
                pinattempt=3; correct=true;
               String b=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\t\t\tSELECT TYPE OF TRANSACTION\n\t\t[B] - BALANCE INQUIRY\n\t\t[W] - WITHDRAWAL\n\t\t[D] - DEPOSIT \n\t\t[C] - CANCEL");
                char pick=b.charAt(0);
                switch (pick)
                {
                   case 'B':
                   case 'b': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account #: " +acct [0]+"\n"+"Account Name: " +name [0]+"\n"+"Balance: "+bal[0],"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);System.exit(0); break;

                   case 'W': 
                   case 'w': 
                    String q =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount to be WITHDRAWN: ");
                   wdamount = Integer.parseInt(q);
                   if ((wdamount<100)||(wdamount%100!=0))
                     {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);

                     }
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [0]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[0]-wdamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); break;

                   case 'D':
                   case 'd':
                    String l = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be DEPOSITED: ");
                    depamount = Integer.parseInt(l);
                    if ((depamount<100)||(depamount%100!=0))
                     {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
                     }
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [0]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[0]+depamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
                    break;
                }
             }break;
           case 2222:
           {
            pinattempt=3; correct=true;
             String c=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\t\t\tSELECT TYPE OF TRANSACTION\n\t\t[B] - BALANCE INQUIRY\n\t\t[W] - WITHDRAWAL\n\t\t[D] - DEPOSIT \n\t\t[C] - CANCEL");
             char pick=c.charAt(0);
             switch (pick)
             {
               case 'B':
               case 'b': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account #: " +acct [1]+"\n"+"Account Name: " +name [1]+"\n"+"Balance: "+bal[1],"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);System.exit(0); break;

               case 'W': 
               case 'w':
                 if (bal[1]<=0)
                 {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot withdraw because you have "+bal[1]+" balance.");
                   System.exit(0);
                 }
               String q =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount to be WITHDRAWN: ");
               wdamount = Integer.parseInt(q);
                 if ((wdamount<100)||(wdamount%100!=0))
                 {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
                 }

             }
           }break;
        case 3333:
        {
        pinattempt=3; correct=true;
          String d=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\t\t\tSELECT TYPE OF TRANSACTION\n\t\t[B] - BALANCE INQUIRY\n\t\t[W] - WITHDRAWAL\n\t\t[D] - DEPOSIT \n\t\t[C] - CANCEL");
          char pick=d.charAt(0);
          switch (pick)
          { 
          case 'B':
          case 'b': 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account #: " +acct [2]+"\n"+"Account Name: " +name [2]+"\n"+"Balance: "+bal[2],"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);System.exit(0); break;

          case 'W': 
          case 'w': 
            String q =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount to be WITHDRAWN: ");
          wdamount = Integer.parseInt(q);
          if ((wdamount<100)||(wdamount%100!=0))
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
            }
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [2]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[2]-wdamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); break;

          case 'D':
          case 'd':
          String l = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be DEPOSITED: ");
          depamount = Integer.parseInt(l);
            if ((depamount<100)||(depamount%100!=0))
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
            }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [2]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[2]+depamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
            break;
          }
        }break;
        case 4444:
        {
        pinattempt=3; correct=true;
          String e=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\t\t\tSELECT TYPE OF TRANSACTION\n\t\t[B] - BALANCE INQUIRY\n\t\t[W] - WITHDRAWAL\n\t\t[D] - DEPOSIT \n\t\t[C] - CANCEL");
          char pick=e.charAt(0);
          switch (pick)
          {
          case 'B':
          case 'b': 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account #: " +acct [3]+"\n"+"Account Name: " +name [3]+"\n"+"Balance: "+bal[3],"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);System.exit(0); break;

          case 'W': 
          case 'w': 
          String q =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount to be WITHDRAWN: ");
          wdamount = Integer.parseInt(q);
          if ((wdamount<100)||(wdamount%100!=0))
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
          }
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [3]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[3]-wdamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); break;    

          case 'D':
          case 'd':
          String l = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be DEPOSITED: ");
          depamount = Integer.parseInt(l);
           if ((depamount<100)||(depamount%100!=0))
           {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
           }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [3]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[3]+depamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
          break;
          }
        }break;

        case 5555:
        {
        pinattempt=3; correct=true;
        String f=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\t\t\tSELECT TYPE OF TRANSACTION\n\t\t[B] - BALANCE INQUIRY\n\t\t[W] - WITHDRAWAL\n\t\t[D] - DEPOSIT \n\t\t[C] - CANCEL");
          char pick=f.charAt(0);
          switch (pick)
          {
          case 'B':
          case 'b': JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account #: " +acct [4]+"\n"+"Account Name: " +name [4]+"\n"+"Balance: "+bal[4],"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); break;

          case 'W': 
          case 'w': 
          String q =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount to be WITHDRAWN: ");
          wdamount = Integer.parseInt(q);
          if ((wdamount<100)||(wdamount%100!=0))
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
          }
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [4]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[4]-wdamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); break;   

          case 'D':
          case 'd':
          String l = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be DEPOSITED: ");
          depamount = Integer.parseInt(l);
           if ((depamount<100)||(depamount%100!=0))
           {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount!");System.exit(0);
           }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Name: " +name [4]+"\n"+"The current BALANCE is now: " +(bal[4]+depamount),"Balance Inquiry",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
           break;
          }
        }break;
       default: //pin validation
        {
        pinattempt++; wrongall++; wrong = false;
        if ((wrongall==3)&&(wrong==false))
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CAPTURED CARD... PLEASE CALL 143-44"); System.exit(0);
        }
        } //pin validation up to here

           }
          }
         }
        }
      }
     }
}
```

Comment: You can use a label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: what do you exactly mean with "how can i return to the first output which is the main menu"? My blind guess in here is to extract the main menue code into a seperate function and call this function at the point where you want to bring up the main menue again.

Comment: what im trying to say is that how can i display the same window(which is the main menu) if for example the user finished withdrawing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said here is the basic idea how to do this (not based on your code since it´s to much, just an example). Seperate the functions from each other and create different methods for them. In the end of the functions you could simply call a method to show the main Menue again. A very basic example of this could look like this.

```
public class Example {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMainMenue();
    }

    /**
     *  A basic method that should allways let you print the menue and input values
     */
    static void printMainMenue() {
        System.out.println("Option a");
        System.out.println("Option b");
        System.out.println("Option c");
        System.out.println("Option d");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("A")) {
            optionA();
        } else if(input.equals("B")) {
            optionB();
        } else if(input.equals("C")) {
            optionC();
        } else if(input.equals("D")) {
            close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            printMainMenue();
        }
    }

    static void optionA () {
        // Do stuff 
        System.out.println("You picked option A");
        printMainMenue();
    }

    static void optionB () {
        // Do stuff 
        System.out.println("You picked option B");
        printMainMenue();
    }

    static void optionC () {
        // Do stuff 
        System.out.println("You picked option C");
        printMainMenue();
    }

    static void close() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

For your code this would mean that you seperate what should happen for the cases `A,C,Q,S and so on` in different methods. In the end you just give these methods a callback to the `printMenue` method, which will bring up your menue again.

If you want a "faster and more dirty solution" just surround the code with an loop `while(true){...}` and break it if the user chose to exit the program.