# how to break a function in java

Tags: java

guys i am a beginner in java ... i want to make a function to loop through a hashmap for example it contains

```
0[3],3[4,5],6[2]
```

and to break when the method isSiteInherited is true else return false... here is what i made

```
  private boolean isInherited() {
  boolean isInherited = false;
    for (Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : siteIndeciesMap.entrySet()) {
      for (Integer index : entry.getValue()) {
          if(isSiteInherited(index)){
              break;
          }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

if not sites are found inherited return false and if it enters the break it should break from all the method ... so what is wrong with this method

Comment: We'd need to see `isSiteInherited()`.

Comment: "it should break from all the method" --> just `return false;` then?

Comment: You **break** loops. To leave the method, simply `return` from it.

Comment: @GhostCat I believe he had to `return true` and not break from his loops, so the duplicate will confuse him and other users won't it?

Comment: When naming variables and other items, name parts should usually comprise natural-language words and as such should be spelled the same (in that part) as the natural-language word to avoid mistakes and confusion for maintainers. Thus `siteIndeciesMap` should be corrected.

Comment: @Nathan I added another duplicate ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be like you want to `return` instead of break.  Without the use of labels, `break` only gets you out of one layer of loops anyway, and in this case, you need to report overall success, which isn't something your current approach does.

```
private boolean isInherited() {
    for (Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : siteIndeciesMap.entrySet()) {
        for (Integer index : entry.getValue()) {
            if (isSiteInherited(index)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: One most certainly can break out of more than one layer of loop at a time, contrary to what is posted here.

Comment: @LewBloch:  If one uses labels, sure; however, I wasn't using labels.  I feel my idiomatic approach is better; now that I'm not on mobile, I can clean it up a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use a label to break from the outer loop (https://stackoverflow.com/a/886979/4949918).

The better way would probably be to use a boolean to say that you've broken from the inner loop in the outer loop.

```
  private boolean isInherited() {
  boolean isInherited = false;
  boolean shouldBreak = false;
    for (Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : siteIndeciesMap.entrySet()) {
      for (Integer index : entry.getValue()) {
          if(isSiteInherited(index)){
              shouldBreak = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (shouldBreak) {
           break;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: That is not the better way. Labels were designed for this situation.