# Nested loops continue java

Tags: java

I have the following for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j =0; j<someArr.length; j++) {
       //after this inner loop, continue with the other loop
    }
}
```

I would like to break out of the inner loop and continue the iteration of the outer loop. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking out of nested loops in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: By using `break;`

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use a combination of `lable` and `break` to jump to where you want like this

```
OUTER_LOOP: for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j =0; j<someArr.length; j++) {
       //after this inner loop, continue with the other loop
     break OUTER_LOOP;

    }
}
```

If you want to break to some where in the outer loop you do like this, put the *lable* where you want to jump to(outside of the current loop) and use that *lable* in the break statement.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    //line code 1
   OUTER_LOOP: // line code 2
    for(int j =0; j<someArr.length; j++) {
       //after this inner loop, continue with the other loop
     break OUTER_LOOP;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`break` does not stop all iterations.**

So if you do the following, you will only `break` out of the nested loop (second `for`) and continue the current iteration of the first `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < someArr.length; j++) {
       break;
       // NOT executed after the break instruction
    }
    // Executed after the break instruction
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need this in the future, you can also use a **continue** statement.

`Break` will leave the loop, but `continue` will skip the rest of the code and jump to the next loop iteration. This will be useful if you want to skip some inner loop iterations but continue on the same outerloop iteration.

Like so:

```
for (int i = ... ) {
    for (int y = ... ) {

    if (some condition) {
        continue;
    }

    // other code here to be executed if some condition is not met

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `break;` in the inner for-loop. if you use break; the outer for-loop will be automatically continue. **Your code will be :-**

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j =0; j<someArr.length; j++) {
       //after this inner loop, continue with the other loop

       if(condition){
            break; //break out of inner loop
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use break

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j =0; j<someArr.length; j++) {
       //after this inner loop, continue with the other loop
       break;
    }
// Executed after the break instruction
}
```